# PyDev - do I have to restart my console to import a newly written function?

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm debugging a program I've written in Eclipse PyDev. It consists of Main.py and S24.py which holds all the functions.

I've generated this really big dictionary using a function in S24.py. Then I realized I needed a function to do some stuff to the data in this dictionary, so I added a function to S24 and tried importing it in the same console that I generated the dictionary in. But it tells me that no such function exists.

I could just restart the console, but then I have to generate the dictionary again. Is there another way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use reload ([the docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#reload)): `reload(S24)`